# ER diagram for an association with 3 Entities

Tags: relationship, entity-relationship, diagram, entities, weak

Can I have a weak relationship with 3 entities, two of them weak and one strong?
Cause I know you can't put a weak relationship with 2 weak entities, but I'm hoping the third party being strong changes that

Comment: Code example, please.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as long as the strong entity is set between the 2 weak entities.